# Regular expressions for the first three characters of a word

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to determine whether or not a word starts with a vowel, one consonant, two consonants, or three consonants. This is what I have so far but I can't get it to work.

```
  def vowel_first(word)
    word[0] =~ /[aeiou]/
  end

  def consonant_first_three(word)
    word[0-2] =~ /^[^aeiou]{3}/
  end

  def consonant_first_two(word)
    word[0-1] =~ /[^aeiou]{2}/
  end

  def consonant_first(word)
    word[0] =~ /[^aeiou]{1}/
  end
```

Comment: Can you describe what doesn't work?

Comment: I found my mistake, I should have been inspecting a range of letter like [0..2] rather than [0-2]

Answer (score 3):

These dashes like those in `word[0-2]` fail. Try substituting them with the `..` operator (resulting in a range).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here appears to be your mangling of the `word` before comparison. In this case `0-1` evaluates to `-1` which means "last character". Likewise, `word[0]` refers to the first character, at index zero, and for `"foo"` would evaluate to `"f"`.

You should just use `word` as-is. The regular expression is anchored correctly and should work provided you give it something to match against.

As a note, using `word.match(/.../)` is often more readable than `word =~ /.../` as that operator is a hold-over from Perl, a language which has never exactly been praised for readability.

Comment: You should not that the regular expressions need the `^` anchor if used with the whole word.

Comment: Yes. Anchors would only be irrelevant if you were doing single character matches.

Answer (score 0):

Is the case of the word that is causing the problem? Try using one of the two options below:

```
def vowel_first(word)
  word[0] =~ /[aeiouAEIOU]/
end

def vowel_first(word)
  word[0] =~ /[aeiou]/i
end
```

Or better still you don't really need to extract letters just make the regex do all the work:

```
def vowel_first(word)
  word =~ /^[aeiou]/i
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check for the number of concurrent consonants at the beginning of the word:

```
leading_consonants = word.match(/^[^aeiou]{,3}/)[0].length
```

When it's zero, the word starts with a non-consonant. This may be good enough depending on your requirements; if you have to account for punctuation and whatnot, you may need to get a bit more clever:

```
matches = word.match(/^([aeiou]?)([^aeiou]{,3})/)
leading_vowel = matches && matches[1].length > 0 || false
leading_consonants = matches && matches[2].length || 0
```